# Get the status of a specific PID

Tags: c, linux, pid

Simple problem but I haven't found an answer, yet. Given a specific PID, can I determine whether that process is active? I'm working on a C program and this is driving me nuts. I read somewhere that `kill(pid,0)` would do the trick, but this returns 0 regardless of whether the process is running or not (or so it seems).

Any hints?

Additional info:
The process I'm interested it is a child initiated by a `fork()`.
The child process should terminate when it reaches the statement `exit(0).` At least that's what I expected... apparently it doesn't.

Further additional info:
The child process that is created with a `fork()` executes a system command which can be different depending on the end-user. The whole thing is part of a batch process, so there's no chance to jump in and fix something. One of the tasks that this child process **may** have to perform is to establish a connection to a remote server in order to store some documents there. This might be another Linux machine or it might be a Win Server (or possibly something else). For this reason I don't want to wait for the child process. I would like the parent to wait a specific length of time (say 10 seconds) and then kill the child process if it hasn't completed by then. By the same token, I don't want the parent process to wait 10 seconds if the child completed its task in 3 milliseconds.

It seems I'm not the first to have this problem.

Comment: By _active_ what exactly do you mean?

Comment: do you want to see the process status in c program or in terminal

Comment: On error, kill(pid,0) returns -1, with errno set appropriately. A zero return means: the process exists (and is yours).

Comment: @wildplasser: I just tested kill(pid,0) and only got 0 return code... so that must mean the process is still active. but why?
By "active" I mean is it still doing something?
I've added a bit more information to the question....

Comment: @AchimSchmitz give my answer a try.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) which will return status information for a given PID.

For an unrelated process you can use `/proc/[pid]/stat` in linux and read the output.

**Regarding the updated information**

There are two scenarios IMO.

First:

The child process is done quickly. Use waitpid (with WNOHANG) and get it's status, then you know how it terminated and that it actually terminated.

Second:

The child process is running. Use waitpid with WNOHANG and check if it is still running. If not do whatever else the parent needs to do, after sufficient time has elapsed, and the child still runs, you can kill it, or do whatever your design sees fit as an appropriate response.

In either way, waitpid is exactly what you need here. The pseudocode just demonstrartes, that you can do other stuff in between and that you don't need to wait 10 seconds even if the child is terminated earlier, bec ause polling like this is not really appropriate.

psuedocode:

```
 pid_t pid;
 pid = fork();
 while(1)
 {
     if(pid == 0)
     {
         if(status = waitpid(pid, WNOHANG))
         {
             if(status != exited)
             {
                 if(checkExpiryTime() == true)
                    kill(pid, SIGKILL);
                 else
                   sleep(x); // or whatever is appropriate in your case.
             }
         }
     }
     else
     {
          // do childstuff here.
     }
 }
```

Comment: waitpid() doesn't do the trick, because the calling process then waits for a change of state (or so I understand). I don't want the calling process to possibly wait on one that is hung.

Comment: Did you read the manpage I linked to? That's what you have WNOHANG for, which is described on that page.

Comment: waitpid() only works for your child processes, you cannot wait for unrelated processes.

Comment: @Devolus: I am familiar with that man page (though I didn't notice your link). The man page states for WNOHANG: return immediately if no child has exited. As I understand it, it means return immediately if it's still running. That's also not what I want. What I really need to know is if the process has stopped yet.

Comment: Wether the child has stopped is shown by waitpid, as there are no stats if the child is still running. As has been pointed out, this works only on child processes though. On thing you might try, is to attach via ptrace and see if the process does something, but of course it requires the privileges. Other than that, what do you expect would be a status of a process if it is still in progress?

Comment: This is getting a bit too complex for a comment, so please see the additional info I'm putting into the original question. Thanks for your efforts, to date.

Comment: @AchimSchmitz please, have you checked my answer? You probably find it useful.

Comment: So it IS a child anyway, in which case waitpid would be appropriate to use. It seems that you may have a wrong expectation on what it means when a process is 'active', so it would be helpfull to clarify what you are actually expecting to see. If the child is not exiting, it is doing "something" and if you want to know what that is you may have to resort to ptrace or look in the /proc fileystem to see if the child is still doing something.

Comment: @Paulo Bu: your answer only just now popped onto my screen. I'm having trouble keeping up with all the comments. :-)

Comment: waitpid(3) *onlŷ* works for child processes. It can't be used to find out about unrelated processes. Use '/proc/<pid>' on Linux (and many other Unices).

Comment: `waitpid` takes 3 arguments. On top of that, in the example, `pid == 0`. I think the example needs to change logic to be `pid != 0`, and call changed to `waitpid(pid,0, WNOHANG)`

Answer (score 3):

Linux doesn't remove the process descriptor once terminated, because parents could need their info later. Linux only removes them completely when the parent issue a `wait()-like` system call on it. Normally this is done by its father, but if the process is orphan, it becomes `init`'s child and `init` eventually issues `wait()-like` system calls to kill zombie process.

Having said that, until the father issues a `wait()-like` call, the child's process descriptor is still allocated with `EXIT_ZOMBIE` status. This is why `kill(pid, 0)` works ok. It is able to find the process descriptor with `pid` field.

`man 3 exit` expands on this further and explains the relationship with `wait(2)` and with zombies processes.

Regarding to `kill(pid, 0)`. It can be used to figure out if a process exists or don't. But it doesn't tell you if is running or waiting for a parent to issue a `wait()` system call to sweep it from kernel's memory.

If it exists `kill()` will return 0. If it doesn't, kill will return `-1` with proper `errno` set (`ESRCH`). If you fork a process, while the father exists, it's its responsibility to issue a `wait()` to get their children termination info. If it doesn't, children will be wandering around until father dies.

Want to make sure? Figure out the `pid` of the child (allegedly) zombie and issue this command:

```
cat /proc/[pid]/status | grep "State"
```

It should show a `Z` for zombie (`man 5 proc`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If the process is a zombie, then it means it already is exited, and in that case waitpid on the child will return it's exit status. As has been said, the process has not exited, so I suspect that the poster wants to somehow observe the process and see if it hangs somewhere.

Comment: But OP said he doesn't want to `wait()` for the child doesn't he?

Comment: He wants to, he just doesn't know it. :)

Comment: I'm going to try a combination like ´waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG | WIFEXITED(0))´ and see what that does. Jeez, I've been doing C programming for all of 3 months. What have I gotten myself into?

Comment: @AchimSchmitz you're dealing here with system calls and processes. Not just C programming. Although simple, this demand a little OS knowledge :) Cheer up!

Comment: I'm only griping, because I have to do this in C... these sort of issues don't crop up in Java or perl. But I'll keep at it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Some more helpful insights and some elegant examples are to be found at http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/signal.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question - a bit confusing now with all the comments - the solution is pretty straight forward.

1. establish a signal handler in the parent.  The default for `SIGCHLD` is to ignore it but by setting the handler the signal will be delivered to the parent when the child completes.  When it does complete reap it with either `wait` or `waitpid`, whichever is really appropriate for your needs.  You do not needlessly `wait` or repeated poll (`waitpid`) this way.
2. set a timer (e.g. `itimer`, `timer_create`, `alarm`, etc).  If the timer goes off before the child completes, `kill` it.  If the child completes first, shut off the timer.  There are obvious (but unavoidable) race conditions but nothing particularly complicated to handle.

Comment: This is more or less how I **did** do it in the end. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a good deal about fork() and signals. I am now in a position to provide a sample which solves the problem. There are a few extras in this code which can be ignored (like the stuff with milliseconds). For the purpose of understanding what it does, the signal handler, the global boolean `stopOnSignal`, and the `kill()` command in the child process are essential aspects. Note that in this case `kill()` just sends a signal to the parent as identified by `getppid().`

So here's my sample (edited to use exec() on 10.01.2014):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <bits/signum.h>

static bool stopOnSignal = false;



uint32_t clockedMilliseconds(clock_t t1, clock_t t2)
{
    if (t2 > t1) { return (t2 - t1) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000); }
    else /* the time has wrapped around since the values were set */
    { return t2 / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000); }
}



void signalHandler(int signum)
{
   printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
   stopOnSignal = true;
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t cpid;
    char * mstr;
    int rc = -999999;
    int krc = 0;
    uint32_t timeoutWait =  10000 ; // default 10 secs
    int count = 0;
    int loops = 0;

    signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler);

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: ./sigparent sleep-milliseconds [timeout-milliseconds]");
        exit -1;
    }

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        printf("%d : failed to start child process.\n", errno);
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) { /* Code executed by child process */

        execl("sleeping_child", argv[1],(char *) NULL);

    }
    else { /* Code executed by parent */

        if (argc > 2) sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&timeoutWait);
        clock_t t1 = clock();
        clock_t t2;

        do { /* loop until child process ends or timeout limit is reached */

            if (count < 100000) count++;
            else {
               loops++;
               printf("loops of 100000 duration = %d \n", loops);
               count = 0;
            }
            t2 = clock();

            if ( clockedMilliseconds(t1, t2) > timeoutWait) {
                krc = kill(cpid,9);
                rc = 3;
                break;
            }
            if ( stopOnSignal == true ) {
                //krc = kill(cpid,9);
                rc = 0;
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        if (rc == -999999) {
                printf("process failed horribly!\n");
        }
        else if (rc == 3) {
            if (krc == 0){ /* child process timed out */
                printf("TIMEOUT, waiting %d ms on pid %d\n",
                       timeoutWait, cpid);
            }
            else { /* attempted timeout failed - result is unpredictable */
                printf("%d : attempted TIMEOUT failed.\n", errno);
                perror("kill");
            }
        }
        else { /* rc == 0 */
             printf("child process ended normally.\n");
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

This might not be pretty, but it works as an effective way to timeout a child process. Save this code in a file - say sigparent.c. You will also need the external program sleeping_child.c.

```
/* sleeping_child */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    int rc = 0;
    int millis;

    if (argc > 2) sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&millis);
    else millis = 2000;

    rc = usleep(millis * 1000);
    printf("slept for %d milliseconds\n",millis);
    printf("parent is %d \n", getppid());
    kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
    return(rc);
}
```

Don't try to run sleeping_child by itself, because it will kill your bash session. To try it out, use the following commands:

```
# to compile...
gcc -o sleeping_child sleeping_child.c
gcc -o sigparent sigparent.c
# to let the child terminate, set the second parameter to greater than the first...
./sigparent 1000 3000
# to cause the parent to timeout the child make the first parameter greater...
./sigparent 10000 3000
```

Many thanks to Duck for the hint about signals. However, there seems to be a more elegant way to do this without the need for signals. A simple example program from a colleague has given me a clue as to how I might achieve my aim with `waitpid().` I'll post the solution when I get it working.

Comment: Honestly Achim, this doesn't appear to make sense or answer your own question.  The parent looping is awful but worse is the child.  You originally said you wanted to execute system commands via the child - whether through the `system` function or the `exec` family was unstated - this won't work for that.  If `exec` is used your child code will be overlaid - no chance to `kill`.  If `system`, which spawns another shell and runs the command, what happens when said command runs too long?  You still won't be able to kill it.

Comment: Hmm... that `system()` spawns a new shell had not occurred to me. I guess I'll have to work on it some more. for the simple case I've used to test this on, it works, though. Besides, what's wrong with the loop? Of cousrse I don't want to print anything like in this example when it comes to the real thing.

Comment: I have a working solution now. It still won't satisfy those who seek elegance in their programming but when you have a deadline: GWWW (Go with what works). The change is not major. The new version uses `exec()` to call an external process after the `fork().` This has the same pid as the child process created by `fork().`

Comment: `exec` is definitely a step in right direction -`system` is about as cheesy and dangerous as it comes - and I can appreciate that you have a deadline but what you have done will only work with child programs that are hardwired to make it work.  If I get a chance later today I'll post something better for you.

Comment: Achem, I added a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Achem, I did this in the cheesiest possible way but this is the idea.  If you want to use milliseconds you can use and `itimer`, or better yet, `timer_create` instead of `alarm`.  If you want to expand it to handle more than one child (or do something useful in the parent) you can do that as well.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t cpid;    
volatile sig_atomic_t done = 0;

void alarmHandler(int signum)
{
    if (kill(cpid, SIGTERM) != -1)
        printf("kill signal sent to child from parent\n");
    else
        if (errno == ESRCH)
            printf("kill could not find child, must already be dead\n");
        else
        {
            perror("kill");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

void childHandler(int signum)
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int status;

    while ((childpid = waitpid( -1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {    
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("Child %d exited naturally\n", childpid);

        if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            printf("Child %d exited because of signal\n", childpid);
    }

    if (childpid == -1 && errno != ECHILD)
    {
        perror("waitpid");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    done = 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sleepSecs;
    int timeoutSecs;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("\nusage: %s sleep-seconds timeout-seconds\n\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &sleepSecs);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &timeoutSecs);

    signal(SIGCHLD, childHandler);
    signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);

    if ((cpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        printf("%d : failed to start child process.\n", errno);
        perror("fork");
        exit( -1);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) //child
    {
        execl("./sleeping_child", "./sleeping_child", argv[1], (char *) NULL);

        perror("execl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else //parent
    {
        alarm(timeoutSecs);

        while (! done)
        {
            sleep(1); // or do something useful instead
        }

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

And the child program does not have to do anything special to die.

```
/* sleeping_child */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    printf("child will sleep for %s seconds\n", argv[1]);

    sleep(atoi(argv[1]));

    exit(0);
}
```

Some sample runs look like this

```
$ simpleReap 3 1
child will sleep for 3 seconds
kill signal sent to child from parent
Child 5095 exited because of signal

$ simpleReap 1 3
child will sleep for 1 seconds
Child 5097 exited naturally
```